# flash player 11 check GPU acceleration

Tags: flash, 3d, hardware-acceleration, flash-player-11

With flash player 11 came 3D GPU acceleration but not every video card can do the job and when there is unsupported video card acceleration is switched to software. Can I check if hardware acceleration is available in order to customize my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must obtain a `Context3D` to view it's `driverInfo`:

```
trace("3d mode: " + context3D.driverInfo);
```

For me, this indicates:

[image: context3d]

Easiest to test for software rendering, hardware accelerated GPU would be indicated by DirectX or OpenGL.

This could be implemented as such:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage3D;
    import flash.display3D.Context3D;
    import flash.display3D.Context3DRenderMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;

    public class X extends Sprite
    {
        public function X()
        {
            super();

            if (ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition("flash.display.Stage3D"))
            {
                stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContext3DCreate);
                stage.stage3Ds[0].requestContext3D();
            }
        }

        private function onContext3DCreate(event:Event):void
        {
            // obtain context
            var t:Stage3D = event.target as Stage3D;
            var context3D:Context3D = t.context3D;

            // detect software mode
            if ((context3D.driverInfo == Context3DRenderMode.SOFTWARE)
                || (context3D.driverInfo.indexOf('oftware') > -1))
            {
                trace("Software mode detected!");
            }

            trace("Flash Version: " + Capabilities.version);
            trace("3D mode: " + context3D.driverInfo);
        }

    }
}
```

For GPU accelerated StageVideo, you listen for `StageVideoAvailabilityEvent` to confirm `StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE`.

This could be implemented as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
    import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;

    public class X extends Sprite
    {
        public function X()
        {
            super();
            stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoState);
        }

        private function onStageVideoState(event:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
        {
            if (event.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE)
                trace("available");
        }

    }
}
```

Once you have a StageVideo, render state is indicated by `StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE`.

```
var stageVideo = stage.stageVideos[0];
stageVideo.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange);

function stageVideoStateChange(event:StageVideoEvent):void
{   
    trace("Render State: " + event.status);
}
```

Render state is derived by `StageVideoEvent.status` and includes:

- `VideoStatus.ACCELERATED` - Decoding and presentation both occur in hardware. (Best performance.)
- `VideoStatus.SOFTWARE` - Presentation in hardware, decoding in software. (Acceptable performance.)
- `VideoStatus.UNAVAILABLE` - No GPU resources are available to handle video, and nothing is displayed. Fall back to a Video object.

Comment: You can't use `stage` in the `Sprite` constructor, you're [missing a step](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13444450/238419).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's an isolated example where `stage` is present as this class is the root view of the application; not convoluted by the standard lifecycle of `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` handlers required by descendent display objects.