# I cannot access stage.stageWidth AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Why cant I access the number stage.stageWidth in my class? It seems to be fine in my main document.

> var b:Number = stage.stageWidth;
>
> trace (b);

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 stage = null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444408/as3-stage-null)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that stage is null. You need to add an event listener to listen when the stage is available. In the constructor add an event listener:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
```

and you the handler onAddedToStage to process your calls to methods that deals with stage and it's properties.

Answer (score 1):

As Creative Magic wrote, you can use the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE.

If your object never gets added to stage and you still need to use stageWidth, you can do two things:

1) Pass the stage object with the constructor or when you are calling a public method of your class:

```
//called from the main class:
var myCustomClassInstance:MyCustomClass = new MyCustomClass(stage);
//and/or
myCustomClassInstance.someMethod(stage);
```

2) Create a static function in your main class that returns you the stage:

```
//code in the main class:
private static var _stage:Stage;

public function Main() {
    _stage = this.stage;
}

public static function getStage():Stage {
    return _stage;
}
//code in custom class:
private function someFunctionWhereYouNeedStage():void {
    var stage:Stage = Main.getStage();
    trace(stage.stageWidth);
}
```